# Can I splice a standard AC power plug onto a 2-pin DIN table lamp cord?

Tags: wiring, electrical, adapter

I've acquired a table lamp with a 20W 12V bulb (possibly from IKEA?). The cord terminates with a female 2-pin DIN (41529) connector that I do not have an adapter for. Am I correct to assume that it needs an AC adapter to connect to my 120V wall socket, or could I simply splice a standard wall plug in place if the DIN connector?

Comment: This really falls under if you need to ask... if you don't know if this lamp requires an adapter please do not try to spice a cable into it.

Comment: Easy thing: unless you are not a trained/certified person, you should not do anything with mains power, as well as you should not work on car brakes if you are not a trained car mechanic. this said, get you a power adaptor for 12V with enough rated power and on the 12V side you are save to connect your lamp cord...

Comment: NO NO NO do not put 120V AC power on this!!!  You need a common old 12V wall-wart.  If you ever got rid of an internet router you probably have one. Put a coaxial/barrel power connector on it that mates to your wall-wart.  *AC mains is quite powerful and dangerous - don't mess with it! I know it seems harmless, but only because a LOT of engineering is done "behind the curtain" to protect appliance users. NEC, UL White Book etc.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIN41259

[image: DIN41259]

(AKA DIN loudspeaker connector)

is not suited for line voltage, so yeah that lamp wants 12V on that connector, a 12V supply capable of 12V and 1800mA or more should be used here instead.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. If the bulb is rated at 12V it will burn/explode.

I would never connect anything to the mains unless it is designed to do so it's not worth the risk.

See if you can track down the missing adapter, if not throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

NO AC PLUG, it almost certainly takes a 12V adapter. Is the plug polarized? (or is it symmetrical?).  You probably also need to determine if it is AC or DC (although an AC bulb probably would be fine on DC, but NOT the other way around!).

Do this by examining the bulb for printed ratings, or a model number for the fixture. See if you can find any information online. Also beware if the socket could take a larger wattage bulb, to insure you don't change a bulb out in the future that overloads the adapter. (See if there is a sticker in the hood stating 'maximum bulb size xxx', and get an adapter big enough for that wattage [volts x amps = watts]).

You will also need enough power (adapter rating) so the adapter won't burn out or catch fire, as Jasen advised above!
12V @ 20W bulb will draw about 1.66Amps, so like Jasen said, a 12V adapter rated around 1800mA to 2 Amps [2000mA]. This will be a larger sized adapter, say 4" long, not the small ones.